# Appengine datastore lost with server restart on Mac with Intellij

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've been developing on and off with Appengine for a while now. I use Intellij for my IDE and I have a Java instance of Appengine.

When running the dev server locally, the database is lost between each restart of the server. This is because Intellij rebuilds the WAR each time and the datastore which is located in the WAR is lost. I know in the documentation that it says the datastore will be persisted; but the documentation implies that you are using the Eclipse plugin.

It used to be that I didn't have this problem because there was a startup param that would specify a different location for the datastore which I setup outside the WAR. I've lost this param and can't find any documentation on it.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following VM param allowed me to change the datastore directory.

-Ddatastore.backing_store=PATH_TO_DATASTORE/local_db.bin

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are just calling the local development server. For Java, the command line equivalent is calling `dev_appserver.sh` (or `.cmd` for Windows folks). If you call:

```
./dev_appserver.sh --help
```

you can see an option `--generated_dir=DIR` that should work for you. Just include this in your IntelliJ run configuration (borrowing Eclipse terminology) and you should be good to go.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm using Intellij to launch the dev server which does not execute the shell script as best I can tell.