# Google AppEngine Dev Server datastore in IntelliJ loses data on restart

Tags: intellij-idea, google-cloud-datastore

Every time I start my local Google AppEngine Dev Server in IntelliJ the datastore is empty. How can I configure AppEngine to persist the datastore?

I have tried adding `--datastore_path=c:\tmp` to Server parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14009082/1389219 with the following VM option:

```
-Ddatastore.backing_store=c:/tmp/local_db.bin
```

Note: It can take up to a couple of minutes before the file appears after you start the program.